# Why won't my function plot?

Tags: plotting, functions, bugs

If I define

```
g[z_] := Which[
  0 <= z <= 0.9,     5*(Min[0.1, z] - Max[0, z - 1]),
  0.9 <= z <= 1.1,   5*(Min[0.1, z] - Max[0, z - 1]) + 5*(Min[1, z] - Max[0.9, z - 1]),
  1.1 <= z <= 2,                                       5*(Min[1, z] - Max[0.9, z - 1]),
  True,              0
  ]
```

and plot using

```
Plot[g[z], {z, 0, 2}]
```

I get

[image]

while if I plot using

```
ListPlot[{#, g[#]} & /@ (Range[1000]/500), PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

I get

[image]

which is what I expect.

Why does `Plot` fail to plot my function as expected?

Comment: `Plot[g[z], {z, 0, 1.2}]` looks fine. Weird...

Comment: The [tag:probability] tag is for questions involving probability functions in MMA, which didn't present here, thus IMO it's not a proper tag here.

Comment: @Silvia: Except that I am "performing probabilistic calculations" and this one is pretty typical, so the issue might (in fact almost certainly will) be encountered by someone else "performing probabilistic calculations".

Comment: `Options[Plot[g[z], {z, 0, 2}], PlotRange]` returns `PlotRange -> {{0., 2.}, {0.5, 0.5}}` so it is shrinking the vertical range. Reporting it.

Comment: @rcollyer: Thanks!

Comment: `Plot[g[z], {z, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> Full]` works also

Comment: Or `PlotRange -> All`.  But do consider Piecewise for mathematical expressions.  `Which` is for programming.

Comment: @Szabolcs the first thing I did is convert it to Piecewise. ofcourse, that is the better way to do it. `g[z_] := Piecewise[{ {5*(Min[0.1, z] - Max[0, z - 1]), 0 <= z <= 0.9},{5*(Min[0.1, z] - Max[0, z - 1]) + 5*(Min[1, z] - Max[0.9, z - 1]), 0.9 <= z <= 1.1},{5*(Min[1, z] - Max[0.9, z - 1]), 1.1 <= z <= 2},{0, True}}];
Plot[g[z], {z, 0, 2}]` But for the plot issue, it did not make a difference. I think this is a bug also.

Comment: @Szabolcs: That could be an alternative answer, especially since it raises some issues about how "programming" should be plotted (and how it *is* vs. how MMA leads one to believe it would be).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Plot[g[z], {z, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, All}]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Should that have been obvious to me? Where is this stuff documented?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I don't think it's obvious. Actually I'd think this is a possible bug. +1 btw

Comment: @Silvia: I'm glad it's not something I missed. Another one of those bugs.

Comment: In fact, `Plot[g[z], {z, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]` will work. I think it a bug, too.